# Trying to implement a digital LPF

Tags: filter, low-pass, digital-filter

So I took this digital LPF from some website:

[image]

And tried implement it first in MatLab to see how it goes, here's the code used:

[image]

So for a frequency of 10 Hz I get this:

[image]

For a frequency of 1000 Hz I get this:

[image]

No attenuation whatsoever, why does this happens?

Edit:

I changed t = linspace(0,1,1000) to t = linspace(0,1,100), along with everything else with a 1000 in it.

Got this for a sine with 100Hz frequency :

[image]

Sine with 1000Hz frequency:

[image]

Comment: What was your matlab sampling frequency?

Comment: In the code i used i sampled the sine wave 1000 times per second, so i would say 1000Hz, but if i change that to 100 nothing really changes

Comment: But the example at the start of your question used 100 Hz. You can't just choose to run at a different sampling rate without changing all the coefficients.

Comment: Also, if your code samples at 1000 times per second, how can you have possibly got to display a 1000 Hz sinewave (1 sample per cycle)? Maybe you meant 1 Hz?

Comment: Do you understand what aliasing is and why you can't have a 100 Hz sin wave with a 100 Hz sampling rate?

Answer (score 1):

Your time coordinates are only sampled in 1/1001 second intervals. Therefore your purported "1000 Hz" wave aliases to become a ~1 Hz wave, which of course will pass through your lowpass filter unimpeded.

If you have similar questions in the future, maybe shift them to [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: See my new edit, time coordinates are now sample in 1/100 second intervals... Still nothing for some reason

Comment: @Scipio That is even worse. The interval must be (ideally much) shorter than 0.5 ms for a 1000 Hz wave. Also make sure, to recalculate your filter constants to adjust for the new sampling rate. And again: If you have more such questions, please move them to dsp.SE. They are not soo much on topic at EE.SE.